# Setting a listbox to a predefined value from generic list

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a listbox, I want to set some of the items in the listbox to be selected. These items are coming from  a System.collections.generic list so in other words, I have a list of

```
ABC  5
DEF  6
PQR  9
```

and a listbox that has around 100 items including `ABC, DEF` and `PQR`. I want to loop through the listbox and list and set these items as selected in my code behind.

How can I achieve this?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `SelectionMode="Multiple"`

### MarkUp

```
<asp:ListBox ID="LBSample" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple">
    <asp:ListItem Text="1" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="2" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="3" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:ListBox>
```

### Code Behind

```
List<string> Str = new List<string> { "1", "3" };

foreach (ListItem obj in LBSample.Items)
{
    if (Str.Contains(obj.Text))
        obj.Selected = true;
}
```

Comment: My listbox has 100 items in it. I need to select only those items that are present in my list so my list has abc, def and PQR so i want abc, def and pqr item to be selected in the listbox and other items should not be selected.